# 'ORA-00905: missing keyword'

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am getting error `'ORA-00905: missing keyword'` while executing this query,the error is in case statement..Please find a solution
 Pls find the query below

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   c_bpartner 



WHERE  c_bpartner.issummary = 'N' 
       AND c_bpartner.isactive = 'Y' 
       AND c_bpartner.isactive = 'Y' 
       AND c_bpartner.issummary = 'N' 
       AND ( CASE 
               WHEN 135 NOT IN (SELECT c_doctype_id 
                                FROM   c_doctype 
                                WHERE  docsubtypeso IN( 'OB', 'ON' )) THEN 
               c_bpartner.isprospect = 'N' 
               ELSE c_bpartner.isprospect = 'Y' 
                     OR c_bpartner.isprospect = 'N' 
             END ) 
       AND c_bpartner.iscustomer = 'Y' 
       AND c_bpartner.isprospect = 'N'
```

Comment: I cleaned your question up for you, next time wrap your code in a code tag and beautify your SQL before you post it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause. You are trying to apply an optional filter, but `CASE` doesn't allow you to apply dynamic alterations to the query. Instead, use `CASE` to project a row specific value which will can be used in a predicate, e.g. Assuming that 'Y' and 'N' are the only possibilities for `isprospect`, try rewriting the case like so:

```
AND c_bpartner.isprospect =
( CASE 
    WHEN 135 NOT IN (SELECT c_doctype_id 
                    FROM   c_doctype 
                    WHERE  docsubtypeso IN( 'OB', 'ON' )) 
    THEN 
        'N' 
    ELSE 
        c_bpartner.isprospect
    END 
)
```

Returning `c_bpartner.isprospect` in the `ELSE` should guarantee a match.